# Retain textbox values on page refresh

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox in a user control uc1. I have embedded this uc1 in a page called default.aspx. My issue is after running the application and entering some data in the textbox, when refresh the page i would like to show the values that i have entered in the textbox and not clear the textbox. I would like help with code on how to achive this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to refresh the page without clearing the value in textbox. I did it as below:
I created a public property in the UC1.vb as below:
Public Property textbox_value() As String

```
    Get
        If Session("textbox1") IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Session("textbox1").ToString()
        Else
            Return ""
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Session("textbox1") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And in the page_load event of the user control i added the code below:
        If IsPostBack Then
            textbox_value= textbox1.Text
        ElseIf Not IsPostBack Then ' First time the page is loaded or when the page is refreshed
            textbox1.Text =  textbox_value
         End If

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable at the top of your aspx.cs page:

```
 public string textboxValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["textboxValue"] != null)
                return ViewState["textboxValue"].toString();
            else
                return "";
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["textboxValue"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Then, in PageLoad(), assign textboxValue a value:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if(!IsPostBack)
textboxValue = MyTextBox.Value;
else
MyTextBox.Value = textboxValue;
}
```

You can also use textboxValue to assign the value of MyTextBox at any time, or use it in any other way that might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This does not solve my issue. After adding the above code when i enter a value in textbox and it looses focus, the value entered in it is lost.

Comment: Hmmm.... You said the textbox was in another user control, uc1. What does that control do? Does it have any affect on what's in the textbox? Is there a method attached to uc1 or the textbox that would affect the textbox when the textbox loses focus? I don't know the answer; just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: I solved it. I will post the code tommorrow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for all asp.net server side controls (`runat="server"`) is to maintain their state. If your textbox is being cleared when your page refreshes, you are likely clearing that value yourself in code.

Are you dynamically adding the textbox or user control? If so, are you doing that during `PageInit`? Adding them later may cause them to lose state.

Comment: Thank you for your help. No, I am not adding the textbox dynamically. And i am also not clearing the text box when the page refreshes.